# How to add a dropdown menu on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a horizontal navigation bar at the top of the page with the following code.What I want is a drop-down menu with the following list of options when I hover over the Columns tab :

Articles

Videos

Interview

Fashion

Here's an image of what I want:
[image]

```css
nav {

  position: fixed;

  top: 0;

  width: 100%;

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90);

  height: 60px;

  overflow: hidden;

  z-index: 100;

}

ul {

  position: absolute;

  right: 50px;

  line-height: 60px;

  height: 60px;

}

ul li {

  display: inline-block;

  position: relative;

  height: 100%;

}

ul li a {

  text-decoration: none;

  font-family: 'raleway';

  font-size: 23px;

  line-height: 60px;

  display: inline-block;

  padding-left: 15px;

  padding-right: 15px;

  color: white;

  box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a>
      <li><a href="about/column.html">Columns</a>
        <li><a href="about/">Team Thrive</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some issues in your code. You have to close your `li` tags. Then you have to add the HTML structure of your dropdown menu before all like this for instance :

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about/column.html">Dropdown here</a>
      <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about/">Team Thrive</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then, a small part of CSS to make it works with hover state on the `li` and playing with `display: block;` and `display: none;`

[See working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c44z19th/7/)

Comment: In HTML 5 there is actually no need to close `li` tags (even though I'd strongly recommend you do it at all times).

Comment: Ah! didn't know about that! Just read this on https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html : _An li element’s end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element._ 
So in his case, it needs no be closed because of the `a` element right ?

Comment: @Vincent G could you add a slide down transition to the drop down menu

Comment: Yes, don't forget to validate the answer if it's resolve your issue. I use jQuery library to do the slideDown() effect : http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Comment: @Vincent G: It doesn't need the end tag because the next <li> start tag will implicitly end the previous one. And that's not even new to HTML5 - ever since li was introduced in HTML 3.2 there has never been a need for end tags. Only XHTML required them, and that's only because it was XML-based.

Comment: Thanks for your précisions. I wish my teachers back in time learned me that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

There is answer to your question on the following official w3schools link: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Answer (score 0):

The W3 schools link posted earlier is a great resource for this particular problem. Played around [in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbfoekwf/) using that resource to get it to work.

Can be done by changing your html to something like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><div class="columns"><a href="about/column.html">Columns</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Articles</a>
    <a href="#">Videos</a>
    <a href="#">Interviews</a>
    <a href="#">Fashion</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about/">Team Thrive</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And add the following to your CSS. You will also need to remove the overflow: hidden from the nav css.

```
.columns {
  display: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.columns:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```